# Tensor product between operators

Tags: linear-algebra

If the state of one qubit can be described by a ray in $\mathbb{C}^2$, then the combined state of an $n$-qubit system can be described by a ray in $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes n}=\mathbb{C}^{2 n}$.

However, if $G_1$ is the Pauli group of one qubit, with the 16 elements
$$G_1=\{i,-1,-i,1\}\times\{I,X,Y,Z\}\,,$$
the Pauli group on $n$ qubits is defined by
$$G_n=\{i,-1,-i,1\}\times\{I,X,Y,Z\}^{\otimes n}$$
which **not the tensor product of $n$ Pauli groups $G_1$** (because $G_n$ contains $4\cdot 4^n$ elements, which does not equal $16^n$). My question thus is: what kind of tensor product do we use on the space of operators on a Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^2$, to define $G_n$ using $G_1$?

(I do understand intuitively that we should disregard global phase (and that therefore the number of operators in the $n$-qubit Pauli group is not $16^n$), and that this can be done by introducing the *projective Hilbert space*, but how do tensor products work on the space of operators on a projective Hilbert space?)

Comment: Check this question and answer, I think taht it might clear you some hings up. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2703/is-the-pauli-group-for-n-qubits-a-basis-for-mathbbc2n-times-2n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group $(G_1)^{n}$ does act on $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes n}$ (you made a typo with $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$ vs $\mathbb{C}^{2^n}$) but the action factors through a quotient thereof. So you can write down this group initially as the set of all $(a_1 \sigma^{0,x,y,z}_1  \otimes \cdots a_n \sigma^{0,x,y,z}_n)$ where the $a_i \in \{ 1,i,-1,-1 \}$ and $\sigma^0=Id_2$. Not using the properties of $\otimes$ to shuffle the $a_i$ through yet. Each tensorand is a copy of $G_1$ and these factors commute amongst each other.

Then when we interpret the symbol $\otimes$, we see that $i \sigma^0_1 \otimes -i \sigma^0_2 \otimes 1 \sigma^0_3 \otimes \cdots \otimes 1 \sigma^0_n$ acts trivially. It is in the kernel of the map $(G_1)^{n} \to Aut((\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes n})$. By understanding this kernel, one sees that $(G_1)^{n}/(ker) \simeq G_n$. There are still some global phases from the $\{1,i,-1,-i\}$ factor.

Suppose one wants to work projectively from the very beginning. Then on 1-qubit we have some subgroup of $PU(2)$. In this case $PG_1 \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2^2$. Then for $n$ qubits you even lose that first global phases factor above and are only left with $(PG_1)^n \simeq PG_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Tensor products *always* mod out $\mathbb C$ (or $\mathbb R$, or whatever field your vector space is defined over).  Thus, there is only *one* phase in the tensor product.  This is also true for the corresponding space of operators, and thus also for $G_1^{\otimes N}$.  This is just the normal definition of the tensor product.

Comment: If we consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ as vector spaces, then $\mathbb{R}^n\otimes\mathbb{R}^m=\mathbb{R}^{nm}$, so tensor products *do not always* mod out $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Of course they do, otherwise $(1,0)\otimes(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)\otimes(-1,0)$ would be different things!

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: I think that Carucel understands you to mean that there are no phases at all --- that rather than modding out $(a\mathbf v \otimes b \mathbf w) - ab(\mathbf v \otimes \mathbf w)$, you're modding out $(a \mathbf v \otimes \mathbf w) - (\mathbf v \otimes \mathbf w)$ and $(\mathbf v \otimes b \mathbf w) - (\mathbf v \otimes \mathbf w)$, which is one possible reading of 'tensor products always mod out scalars'.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Maybe, but I'd interpret "mod out C" as "mod out C once", not "mod out C as often as you can".

Comment: We both understand how that goes, though someone asking the same question as Carucel might not.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap True. To be fair, I wrote this as a comment but then felt I might post it as well as a (very concise) answer.  Also, given that the OP accepted the other answer they must have some level of technical understanding on linear algebra. (And I also never actively realized this modding out in tensor products, until someone pointed it out to me (in fact, I asked a mathematician what they meant by $\otimes_N$), at which point I suddenly understood.)