# Can arbitrary matrices be decomposed using the Pauli basis?

Tags: mathematics, matrix-representation, pauli-gates, textbook-and-exercises

Is it possible to decompose a hermitian and unitrary matrix $A$ into the sum of the Pauli matrix Kronecker products?

For example, I have a matrix 16x16 and want it to be decomposed into something like $$A =\sum_{i,j,k,l}h_{ijkl}\sigma_i\otimes\sigma_j\otimes\sigma_k\otimes\sigma_l$$
I can't find any clear explanation how it can be done.
I found only this for two-dimentional case:
https://michaelgoerz.net/notes/decomposing-two-qubit-hamiltonians-into-pauli-matrices.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For any matrix $A$ we can write 
$$
A =\sum_{i,j,k,l}h_{ijkl}\cdot \frac{1}{4}\sigma_i\otimes\sigma_j\otimes\sigma_k\otimes\sigma_l,
$$
where
$$
h_{ijkl} = \frac{1}{4}\text{Tr}\big((\sigma_i\otimes\sigma_j\otimes\sigma_k\otimes\sigma_l)^\dagger \cdot A\big) = \frac{1}{4}\text{Tr}\big((\sigma_i\otimes\sigma_j\otimes\sigma_k\otimes\sigma_l) \cdot A\big) 
$$
This is because 256 matrices $\frac{1}{4}\sigma_i\otimes\sigma_j\otimes\sigma_k\otimes\sigma_l$ form an orthonormal basis in the linear space of all $16 \times 16$ matrices under Hilbert-Schmidt inner product given by $( A,B) = \text{Tr}(B^\dagger A)$.

If you have an orthonormal basis $e_i$ then any element of a Hilbert space can be written as $v = \sum_i (v,e_i)e_i$. That's it.

If dimension is not power of 2, then it's impossible, of course. But there are generalizations of Pauli matrices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices. So the similar formula can be written.

Comment: Is it true if A is not hermitian ?

Comment: @Nichola, yes, $A$ can be any matrix

Answer (score 14):

$\newcommand{\bs}[1]{{\boldsymbol #1}}
\newcommand{\tildebssigma}{\tilde{\bs\sigma}}
\newcommand{\bssigma}{{\bs\sigma}}$Yes, products of Pauli matrices form a basis for the set of Hermitian matrices (of dimensions that are powers of $2$).

More specifically, fix an integer $n$ and let $N\equiv 2^n$, define $\bssigma\equiv(\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_y)$, and $\tildebssigma\equiv (I,\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_y)$.
Moreover, let $J\in\{0,1,2,3\}^{n}$ be a tuple of $n$ integers with each $J_i\in\{0,1,2,3\}$.
Consider the matrices of the form
$$
\tildebssigma_J\equiv\prod_{k=1}^n \tildebssigma^{(k)}_{J_k},
$$
where $\tildebssigma_j^{(k)}$ denotes the Pauli matrix $\tildebssigma_j$ applied on the $k$-th qubit.
You can check that these are all Hermitians. Moreover, $\tildebssigma_J$ is traceless for all $J\neq(0,...,0)$ (for which $\tildebssigma_{(0,...,0)}=I$).

There are $4^n=N^2$ matrices of this form (one for each possible choice of $J$), and for any pair of tuples $J,K$ we have
$\operatorname{Tr}(\tildebssigma_J\tildebssigma_K)=N\delta_{JK}$.
Moreover, the space of Hermitian $N\times N$ matrices also has dimension $N^2$. It follows that $\{\tildebssigma_J\}_J$ is a basis for this space. Explicitly, you can decompose an arbitrary Hermitian matrix $H$ as
$$H=\frac{1}{N}\sum_J \operatorname{Tr}(\tildebssigma_J H)\tildebssigma_J.$$
Note that the coefficients in any such expansion are always *real*. This is not by chance. Indeed,  being more careful, we should state that the set of *real* linear combinations of products of Pauli matrices give the set of Hermitian matrices (notice that if $A$ is Hermitian then $\alpha A$ is Hermitian iff $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, so this is not surprising).

More general matrices can be generated if we allow for complex coefficients in the expansion.
Indeed, note that
$$\frac{I+Z}{2}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\qquad \frac{I-Z}{2}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \\
\frac{X+iY}{2}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\frac{X-iY}{2}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Therefore the complex span of Pauli matrices can be used to generate arbitrary $2\times 2$ matrices. This then translates into the same result for arbitrary $2^n$-dimensional spaces, as if $\mathcal V\equiv\{v_k\}$ is a basis for $V$, then the sets of tensor products of elements of $\mathcal V$ form a basis for $V^{\otimes n}$.

This is a special instance of the more general fact that any matrix can be decomposed uniquely as sum of a Hermitian and a skew-Hermitian matrix, as
$$A=\frac{A+A^\dagger}{2}+i\frac{A-A^\dagger}{2i},$$
and the fact that products of Pauli matrices give you a basis for the set of Hermitian matrices.

Comment: I realised after answering that this is essentially a duplicate of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2703/55