# How to express $n$-qubit Hermitian operator with Pauli matrices

Tags: mathematics, matrix-representation, pauli-gates, linear-algebra

How can we prove that all $n$-qubit Hermitian matrices can be written in terms of Pauli matrices $I$, $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ as
$$
\sum_{W_k \in \{I, X, Y, Z\}} a_{W_1,\dots,W_n}W_{1}\otimes ... \otimes W_{n}
$$
where $a_{W_1,\dots,W_n} \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: See this [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11899/how-can-i-decompose-a-matrix-in-terms-of-pauli-matrices) as well.

Comment: And [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2703/is-the-pauli-group-for-n-qubits-a-basis-for-mathbbc2n-times-2n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach is to overdo it a little and show that $n$-qubit Pauli operators form an *orthogonal* basis in the real vector space $L_H(\mathbb{C}^{2^n})$ of $n$-qubit Hermitian operators with appropriately defined inner product. To that end, we first show that $\langle A,B\rangle_{HS}:=\mathrm{tr}(A^\dagger B)$ is an inner product$^1$. Next, we calculate that for any two Pauli operators $W=W_1\otimes\dots\otimes W_n$ and $W'=W'_1\otimes\dots\otimes W'_n$ we have $\langle W,W'\rangle_{HS}=0$ if and only if $W\ne W'$. This implies$^2$ linear independence. Finally, there is a linear bijection between $L_H(\mathbb{C}^k)$ and $\mathbb{R}^{k^2}$, so $\dim L_H(\mathbb{C}^k)=k^2$. But there are $4^n$ Pauli operators in $L_H(\mathbb{C}^{2^n})$, so they form a basis.

---

<sup>$^1$ The function $\langle .,.\rangle_{HS}$ is known as the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product.

$^2$ Because the coefficient in front of $W_k$ in a linear combination $A$ is proportional to $\langle W_k,A\rangle_{HS}$.</sup>

Comment: Thank you this is super helpful!