# Is there an efficient algorithm for decomposing an arbitrary Hamiltonian into Pauli strings?

Tags: pauli-gates, hamiltonian

Basically the title. If I have a $2^N\times 2^N$ Hamiltonian $H$ of random numbers (we can take the Hamiltonian as normalized if we want) and $N$ is an integer, is there an efficient way of writing
$$
H = \sum_{i}{\beta_iP_i}
$$
where $\beta_i \in \mathbb{C}$ and $P_i$ is a Pauli string and the sum ranges over all such possible tensor product combinations of the Pauli group, $\{I,X,Y,Z\}$. Apologies if my notation is non-standard; let me know if any clarification is needed.

Also, I say efficient because I am aware of such solutions as [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8725/can-arbitrary-matrices-be-decomposed-using-the-pauli-basis) and [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2703/is-the-pauli-group-for-n-qubits-a-basis-for-mathbbc2n-times-2n), but these seem to become exponentially hard in $N$.

Comment: Certainly, this seems impossible unless there is some additional structure imposed on $H$. Asking for $H$ in the Pauli string basis, given an $H$ in the standard basis requires matrix multiplication, which is why you will always be polynomial in the dimension of the matrix (i.e. exponential in $N$).

Comment: @Condo While it is true that it is exponentially hard -- just *specifying* H already requires an exponential number of parameters, it does not require matrix multiplication (at least not in the sense of multiplying two $2^N\times 2^N$ matrices).

Comment: The most efficient way (if $H$ is just a full matrix) is to vectorize $H$ (which makes it a $4^N$-component vector) and then apply a basis transformation to the Pauli basis on each of the $4$-dimensional blocks; this can be achieved as a sequence of multiplication of a $4\times 4^{N-1}$ matrix with a $4\times 4$ matrix.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Ah yes, I completely mistyped what I meant. What I was trying to say was that the change of basis transformation requires matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best is the one proposed recently in https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.16378. In my tests, I could decompose $N=11$-qubit Hamiltonian in about $ \sim 170$ minutes. It would be a challenge, but, very useful to improve this further by finding a better algorithm.

Comment: Appendix B of https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.08550 also works

Comment: I think that's little different approach from OP, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Your output size is $4^n$ numbers, so you're certainly not going to do better than $\Omega(4^n)$ complexity. At least, not without some sort of sparsity guarantee and some way to compute those big terms analogous to the [sparse fast fourier transform](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/netmit/sFFT/).

Anyways, it turns out that you can get all $4^n$ numbers by interpreting your matrix as a vector and simulating applying the same quantum circuit you would apply to measure in the Bell basis. This takes $O(4^n)$ space and $O(n 4^n)$ time:

[image]

In more classical computing terms: take your matrix of coefficients, permute each column so that the entry at offset $j$ in column $k$ ends up at offset $j \oplus k$ in column $k$, then apply the classical [Hadamard transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform) to each column (or maybe each row? I can never keep that straight). The matrix now contains the Pauli term coefficients.